# Exception: The first BizTalk Host must be an "In-Process" type host with the "Default host in group"

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

While deploying biztalk application, getting below error:

**COMException: The first BizTalk Host must be an "In-Process" type host with the "Default host in group" and "Host tracking" options set**

Please share resolution.

=================================
Above issue has been resolved.

But now i got below error:
Create MQSC ReceiveHandler for: HeartBeat on 
**error : COMException: No instance was found with the specified key.

This could be the result of the instance being deleted by another BizTalk Admin session.\r**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to enable tracking on your only BizTalk Host. Most of the times, this one is called `BizTalkServerApplication`. Are you sure tracking is enabled?

To check this, go to the BizTalk Administration Console and take a look at the Hosts and Hosts Instances. There should be at least 1 host there with 1 host instance and with tracking enabled.

Right-click the Host or Host Instance and make sure tracking is enabled.

Comment: Thanks Pieter. It worked. but i got another error. Please have a look at my question(edited)

Comment: I haven't encountered this issue before I'm afraid. Perhaps someone else has that can answer here?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you don't let BizTalk Configuration create the default BizTalkServerApplication host and you haven't created any other hosts manually.

The resolution is pretty simple, create BizTalkServerApplication as an In Process Host.  It will automatically have the Default Flag set.